# Getting the first solution instance

Tags: equation-solving

How do I get *Mathematica* to stop a solver and give a result as soon as it finds the first solution instance?

I tried this:

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && x > 5, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

Comment: Surely, you meant `Solve` not `Soln`?

Comment: @m_goldberg True! Thank you. How to stop the calculation after the first instance? Best

Comment: Use `FindInstance` instead of `Solve`?

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar True! Thank you. More precisely does there exists a code to stop the computation after a precise number of instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && x > 5, {x, y, z}, Integers, 1]
(* Results {{x -> 7, y -> 0, z -> 7}} *)
```

This tries to find 1 instance.
If you want to look for two solutions:

```
 FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && x > 5, {x, y, z}, Integers, 2]
(* Results  {{x -> 15, y -> -20, z -> -25}, {x -> 919, y -> 0, z -> 919}} *)
```

However, look out because you may receive a warning for 3 or more on failing to find any additional integer solutions and being unable to prove that more do not exist.

```
FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && x > 5, {x, y, z}, Integers, 25]

 FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 2 instance(s), 
but it was not able to prove 3 instances do not exist. >>
```

If you want any more solutions, try using different `RandomSeed` ([see docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)) or alternatively this code (not the fastest) which generates many random solutions as `{x,y}` pairs from which you can easily get `z`:

```
Select[DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[PowersRepresentations[#, 2, 2] & /@ 
  RandomInteger[{2, 50000}, 5000], 1]], 
 IntegerQ@Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2] && #[[1]] > 5 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

I really prefer `Solve` for tackling this problem. If `Solve` is suitably constrained, it will deliver a much more interesting sample of the solution space.

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && 5 < x < 20 && 0 < y < 50 && 0 < z, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 7, y -> 24, z -> 25}, {x -> 8, y -> 15, z -> 17}, 
>  {x -> 9, y -> 12, z -> 15}, {x -> 9, y -> 40, z -> 41}, 
>  {x -> 12, y -> 5, z -> 13}, {x -> 12, y -> 9, z -> 15}, 
>  {x -> 12, y -> 35, z -> 37}, {x -> 15, y -> 8, z -> 17}, 
>  {x -> 15, y -> 20, z -> 25}, {x -> 15, y -> 36, z -> 39}, 
>  {x -> 6, y -> 8, z -> 10}, {x -> 8, y -> 6, z -> 10}, 
>  {x -> 10, y -> 24, z -> 26}, {x -> 12, y -> 16, z -> 20}, 
>  {x -> 14, y -> 48, z -> 50}, {x -> 16, y -> 12, z -> 20}, 
>  {x -> 16, y -> 30, z -> 34}, {x -> 18, y -> 24, z -> 30}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you ! Thank you ! Thank you !